# winform aspnet.identity "CREATE DATABASE permission is not granted in master"

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use aspnet.identity. I have successfully did it in an VSTO add-in project. But a winform project that I am making now is throwing an error "CREATE DATABASE permission is not granted in master"

I am using the following three steps

Step 1: Used nuget to install aspnet.indentity 
Step 2: Added connection string to app.config file

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="[[MY CONNECTION STRING HERE]]" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Step 3: Used the following two methods

```
        public bool VerifyUserNamePassword(string userName, string password)
        {
            var usermanager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new IdentityDbContext()));

            try
            {
                return usermanager.Find(userName, password) != null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public IList<string> GetUserRole(string userName, string password)
        {
            var usermanager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new IdentityDbContext()));
            if (usermanager.Find(userName, password) != null)
            {
                var userID = usermanager.Find(userName, password).Id;
                return usermanager.GetRoles(userID);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: This error usually comes when you create a DB with a user who has not enough permissions. Are you using windows authentication or do you have a user in your connection string?

Comment: The connection string I provided points to a DB where identity tables are already created. It is not even pointing to the "master" database. One more crucial information is the very same DB is being used in my VSTO excel add-in project and there same code is working.

Comment: Just to rule out the DB, can you please try creating a user with full permissions and updating your connection string. Do you have the DB name specified something like,

public Context(): base("MySchoolDB") assuming you are trying Code-First approach.